# How to optimize the query of datetime condition?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have a table `cashflow` and 4 index [`is_dp`], [`is_wd`], [`is_dis`], [`time`].

```
`is_dp`   tinyint(1) => (0,1)
`is_wd`   tinyint(1) => (0,1)
`is_dis`  tinyint(1) => (0,1)
`time`    datetime
```

This table have 3 million up rows.

My query is :

```
1. SELECT * FROM `cashflow` WHERE is_dp = 1 AND time >= '2019-05-01 00:00:00' AND time <= '2019-05-31 23:59:59';

2. SELECT * FROM `cashflow` WHERE is_wd = 1 AND time >= '2019-05-01 00:00:00' AND time <= '2019-05-31 23:59:59';

3. SELECT * FROM `cashflow` WHERE is_dis = 1 AND time >= '2019-05-01 00:00:00' AND time <= '2019-05-31 23:59:59';
```

The index `time` is not working with each of the keys [`is_dp`], [`is_wd`], [`is_dis`].

EXPLAIN:

```
| query | possible_keys  |  key   | key_len |  ref  | rows    | Extra                               |
| 1.    | is_dp,time     | time   | 8       | NULL  | 242616  | Using index condition; Using where; |
| 2.    | is_wd,time     | is_wd  | 1       | const | 494546  | Using where;                        |
| 3.    | is_dis,time    | is_dis | 1       | const | 1089870 | Using where;                        |
```

How to optimize it?

or Composite Key is a good way?

```
ADD KEY `dp_time` (`is_dp`,`time`);
ADD KEY `wd_time` (`is_wd`,`time`);
ADD KEY `dis_time` (`is_dis`,`time`);
```

Thank you really much!

Comment: Yes, a composite index will probably help.

Comment: @Barmar Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *those* 3 `SELECTs`, you need all 3 of *those composite* indexes.  The suggested 4-column index will not be optimal for any of them.

Indexes are used from the left.  With `INDEX(is_dp, is_wd, is_dis, time)`, query 1 can use `is_dp`, but then quit with the index when it hits `is_wd`.  The other two queries simply cannot use the index.

(What I just said is not totally correct, but it is they are *not* efficient, even if used.)

My [*Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) explains building optimal indexes a bit more.

`Using index condition` -- implies that InnoDB will do most or all of the filtering inside the Engine, not the Handler.  (OK, that is a cryptic explanation; the query is not a good vehicle for discussing ICP (Index Condition Pushdown).)

`Using where` - Some of the `WHERE` was used.  Rather vague.

`key_len = 1` - implies that only 1 byte of the index was used; presumably `is_wd`, etc.

Comment: @James If I use composite indexes, I know it will use large storage to create those composite indexes. because the `time` field type is datetime. Is way better than all 3 of those composite indexes?

Comment: @BinglinLai - No, put the range (`time`) last, like I put `aaa` last.

Comment: @James Got it. Thank you very much.